Joint pdf with minimum for iid exponential random variables
Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be iid exponential$(1)$ random variables. I would like to find the joint pdf of $X_i, Y$ where $Y = \min_i(X_i)$. If $x \leq y$, then $X_i \leq x$ guarantees that $Y \leq y$, so
$$P(X_i \leq x, Y \leq y) = P(X_i \leq x).$$
If $x > y$, then either $y < X_i \leq x$ and the minimum of the remaining $n - 1$ variables is at most $y$, or $X_i \leq y$ and thus $Y \leq y$ automatically. So
$$P(X_i \leq x, Y \leq y) = P(y < X_i \leq x)P(\min_{j \neq i}(X_j) \leq y) + P(X_i \leq y).$$
Using the fact that the minimum of $m$ iid exponential$(1)$ random variables has a exponential$(1 / m)$ distribution, we see that the joint cdf of $X_i,Y$ is given by
\begin{alignat*}{1}
f_{X_i,Y}(x,y) &= P(X_i \leq x, Y \leq y) \\
&= \begin{cases}
P(X_i \leq x) & x \leq y \\
P(y < X_i \leq x)P(\min_{j \neq i}(X_j) \leq y) + P(X_i \leq y) & x > y
\end{cases} \\
&= \begin{cases}
1 - e^{-x} & x \leq y \\
(e^{-y} - e^{-x})(1 - e^{-(n - 1)y}) +  1 - e^{-y}& x > y.
\end{cases} \\
\end{alignat*}
Taking the mixed partial, we obtain the joint pdf
$$f_{X_i,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}
0 & x \leq y \\
(n - 1)e^{-x - (n - 1)y} & x > y.
\end{cases}$$
This can't be correct, however, as this function doesn't integrate to $1$:
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\int f_{X_i, Y}(x, y) &= \int_0^{\infty} \int_y^{\infty} (n - 1)e^{-x - (n - 1)y} \hspace{1mm} dx \hspace{1mm} dy \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} (n - 1)e^{-(n - 1)y}e^{-y} \hspace{1mm} dx \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} (n - 1)e^{-ny} \hspace{1mm} dy \\
&= \frac{n - 1}{n} \\
&\neq 1.
\end{alignat*}
I'm not seeing where things went wrong.
